# Did I lose my untracked files after running git stash and switching branches?

Tags: git

My branch "A" was in the following state:

```
New      -- foo.cs
New      -- bar.cs
Modified -- baz.cs
```

I ran `git stash` followed by `git checkout master`, then `git pull`.

I did some work on master, created a new branch, and committed changes there.

I then checked-out "A" again and ran `git stash apply`.

Now there are errors all over my code from references from `foo.cs` and `bar.cs`, and those files are gone.

I now realize that I should have just committed my changes or used `git stash save --include-untracked`.

Is there a way to get my files back?

If not, then I feel like the danger of using `git stash` needs to be emphasized more.

Comment: None of the commands you listed would have deleted untracked files.

Comment: What shows when you do `git stash list`? Also, were those new files tracked or untracked?

Comment: Untracked new files aren't stashed so they follow you when you checkout mastrer. My guess is that you then commited your files on the master branch.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was that I moved the untracked files to `master` when I checked out that branch.

`git stash apply` on my original branch added back the changes made to tracked files, but the untracked files were no longer on my branch; they were on `master`.

Comment: The untracked files are not on any branch. They are not tracked, remember? They exist only in the working tree and since they are not tracked, they are not affected by checkouts, except when files with the same names already exist in the directory on the branch you checkout.